# How to use order by in union all

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union

I have 2 table and i have used union all to combine both table.
I have strCreatedOn column for timestamp. Now i am not able use order by clause in it

```
select nVendorId,
        'bank'as change_column,   
        nRequestType as change_type,
        strCreatedOn as Timestamp,
        nItemState as status       
from vaamoz_admin.tblbankdetails
 where   nItemState = '1' AND nRequestType='4'

union all

select nVendorId,
        'kyc' as change_column, 
        nRequestType as change_type ,
        strCreatedOn as Timestamp,
          nItemState as status

 from vaamoz_admin.tblkycdetails
 where nItemState = '1' AND nRequestType='4'
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL expects parentheses around each query, and `order by` afterwards, as explained [in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html):

> To use an `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` clause to sort or limit the entire `UNION` result, parenthesize the individual `SELECT` statements and place the `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` after the last one.

So:

```
(
    select 
        nVendorId,
        'bank'as change_column,   
        nRequestType as change_type,
        strCreatedOn as Timestamp,
        nItemState as status       
    from vaamoz_admin.tblbankdetails
    where nItemState = 1 and nRequestType = 4
) union all (
    select 
        nVendorId,
        'kyc', 
        nRequestType,
        strCreatedOn,
        nItemState
    from vaamoz_admin.tblkycdetails
    where nItemState = 1 AND nRequestType = 4
 )
 order by Timestamp
```

Notes:

- there is no need to repeat the column names in the second query (the names defined in the first query spawn in the other one(s))
- `nItemState` and `nRequestType` look like number, so they should treated as such (I removed the single quotes around the numbers)

Comment: *MySQL expects parentheses around each query* No. The parenthesis over separate queries are excess in this case (but they may be used nevertheless). They **must** be used only when you want to apply ordering (and limiting) to separate query, not to combined rowset.

Comment: @Akina: yes. The question is about (outer) order by, for which parentheses are required.

Comment: No. Please read a sentence below the example. *A statement without parentheses is equivalent to one parenthesized as just shown.*

Comment: The words written with italic in my comment font are direct citate from Reference Manual by the link provided in your answer. You may verify this using searching by web-page.

Answer (score 0):

In most databases, you can just add an `order by`:

```
select nVendorId, 'bank'as change_column, nRequestType as change_type,
       strCreatedOn as Timestamp, nItemState as status       
from vaamoz_admin.tblbankdetails
where nItemState = '1' AND nRequestType='4'
union all
select nVendorId, 'kyc' as change_column, nRequestType as change_type ,
       strCreatedOn as Timestamp, nItemState as status
from vaamoz_admin.tblkycdetails
where nItemState = '1' AND nRequestType='4'
order by Timestamp;
```

In some, you need a subquery:

```
select t.*
from ((select nVendorId, 'bank'as change_column, nRequestType as change_type,
             strCreatedOn as Timestamp, nItemState as status       
       from vaamoz_admin.tblbankdetails
       where nItemState = '1' AND nRequestType='4'
      ) union all
      (select nVendorId, 'kyc' as change_column, nRequestType as change_type ,
           strCreatedOn as Timestamp, nItemState as status
       from vaamoz_admin.tblkycdetails
       where nItemState = '1' AND nRequestType='4'
      )
     ) t
order by Timestamp;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4f063ffad80ecab958e861bbda0e8215) is a simple example using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select t.* from 
(
select nVendorId,
        'bank'as change_column,   
        nRequestType as change_type,
        strCreatedOn as Timestamp,
        nItemState as status       
from vaamoz_admin.tblbankdetails
 where   nItemState = '1' AND nRequestType='4'

union all

select nVendorId,
        'kyc' as change_column, 
        nRequestType as change_type ,
        strCreatedOn as Timestamp,
          nItemState as status

 from vaamoz_admin.tblkycdetails
 where nItemState = '1' AND nRequestType='4'
) as t order by t.Timestamp
```